# Function that assigns properties

Tags: function-construction, downvalues

I want to create a function that creates and assigns properties to a symbol. In theory this would behave similarly to the `NonzeroValues` property of `SparseArray`s.

Here's what I currently have, and where I'd like to go.

```
func[x_] := Module[{data},
  (*data=Import data from source based on x*)
  HoldPattern[func[x, "Length"]] = Length@data;
  HoldPattern[func[x, "Dimensions"]] = Dimensions@data;
 ]


func[15,"Length"]
```

> `225`

However, I'd like this to work more like this:

```
var=func[15];

var["Length"]
```

> `225`

It would be ideal not to have to calculate this every time a property is retrieved. For efficiency sake, importing the data every time a property is retrieved isn't feasible.

How so I define these subvalues at the first function call and store them for fast retrieval later?